# Template function overload for std::complex

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, complex-numbers

I have a function that generates random number for my array. I created two overloads for floating-point numbers and integers as follows:

```
template <typename T, int M = 0>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value && std::is_scalar<T>::value,MyArray<T,M> >::type
Random()
{
    //...
}

template <typename T, int M = 0>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value && std::is_scalar<T>::value, MyArray<T,M> >::type
Random()
{
    //...
}
```

These functions can be called with:

```
MyArray<int> i    = Random<int>();
MyArray<double> d = Random<double>();
```

I would like to achieve the same but with `std::complex<T>`, where `T` can be any floating point type (initially double and float are good enough). I want to be able to do this:

```
//This is what I'm trying to achieve
MyArray<std::complex<double> > = Random<std::complex<double>>();
MyArray<std::complex<float > > = Random<std::complex<float >>();
```

I was unable to achieve this exactly, but was able to achieve:

```
Random<std::complex,double>()
```

using template template parameters, which is not what I'm looking for.

How can I get the overload with `<std::complex<double>>` (or float) to work?

Comment: std::is_same<T, complex<T>>::value doesn't work?

Comment: @DeiDei How could that work? That looks recursive! I'll try that anyway.

Comment: @DeiDei Nope... doesn't work. It says no matching function for the overload `MyArray<std::complex<double> >`.

Comment: `template<typename T, int M = 0>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, complex<double> >::value, MyArray<complex<double>,M> >::type` Are you sure?

Comment: @DeiDei I don't want to specialize for double. I want `double` to be detected. What if it's float? I don't want to rewrite the function for float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that creating an extractor helper (to, by example, extract `float` from `std::complex<float>`) as

```
template <typename T>
struct extractType;

template <template <typename ...> class C, typename D>
struct extractType<C<D>>
 { using subType = D; };
```

you can use it and write

```
template <typename T, int M = 0>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, std::complex<
               typename extractType<T>::subType>>::value
            && std::is_floating_point<typename extractType<T>::subType>::value
            && std::is_scalar<typename extractType<T>::subType>::value,
         MyArray<T,M> >::type
Random ()
 { return MyArray<T,M>{}; }
```

or simply

```
template <typename T, int M = 0>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,
            std::complex<typename extractType<T>::subType>>::value,
            MyArray<T,M> >::type
Random ()
 { return MyArray<T,M>{}; }
```

if you can consider obvious that the template argument of `std::complex` is floating and scalar.

**--- EDIT ---**

Added a full example (well... with a false `MyArray`)

```
#include <array>
#include <complex>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, int M = 0>
using MyArray = std::array<T, 10U>;


template <typename T>
struct extractType;

template <template <typename ...> class C, typename D>
struct extractType<C<D>>
 { using subType = D; };


template <typename T, int M = 0>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value && std::is_scalar<T>::value,MyArray<T,M> >::type
Random ()
 { return MyArray<T,M>{}; }

template <typename T, int M = 0>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value && std::is_scalar<T>::value, MyArray<T,M> >::type
Random ()
 { return MyArray<T,M>{}; }

template <typename T, int M = 0>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,
            std::complex<typename extractType<T>::subType>>::value,
            MyArray<T,M> >::type
Random ()
 { return MyArray<T,M>{}; }



int main()
 {
   MyArray<int>                 i = Random<int>();
   MyArray<double>              d = Random<double>();
   MyArray<std::complex<float>> c = Random<std::complex<float>>();
 }
```

**-- EDIT 2 --**

Solution and example modified according OP improvement (direct use of `extractType<T>::subType` instead of use of a default typename).

Comment: Would be great if you could create a minimal example in http://ideone.com/ for example. I'm trying to implement this (it looks really fancy, I have to say), but I'm still getting "no matching function or call...".

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist - added a full example; compile with my clang++ and g++; hope this helps

Comment: For some very weird reason... in my code, `D` is being guessed as `int`... I have no idea why! Your code works, and a simple example with extractType works, but my code makes the wrong guess of the type... the funny part is that if I input `Random<std::complex<double>,0,double>`, it works... If I remove that last `double`, it doesn't work... any idea?

Comment: Even funnier... if I do `Random<std::complex<double>,0,extractType<std::complex<double>::SubType>`, it works... g++ is actively making a wrong guess...

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist show the code, don't keep us guessing ;)

Comment: @krzaq I think I got it... it's because there's a parameter that depends on `D` in the arguments list (not shown in the examples), and I'm inputting an integer value there, and the compiler uses that to guess the type. It's not that smart :)

Comment: You may think it's hilarious, but type deduction trumps default type values ;) That's why I'd rather use tag dispatching.

Comment: @krzaq Actually I found a "fancy" way to fix it. Instead of using `D` in the argument list, I used `typename extractType<T>::subType`, and that guaranteed that it depends on the first template parameter, and not on the number I put in the arguments ;-)

Comment: Btw, +1 also because I loved that `extractType`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist - nice improvement; and krzaq is right: the use of deduction using default types is a little dangerous; modified my answer absorbing your improvement

Answer (score 3):

Use tag dispatch to select the overload you want. This code requires C++14, but it can be easily made to work with C++11. You'd lose on readability though (repeated function bodies, no `enable_if_t`)

First, define tags:

```
struct integral_tag{};
struct floating_point_tag{};
struct complex_tag{};
struct error_tag{};
```

Some helper templates (tag selection, `complex` detection):

```
namespace detail
{

template<typename T> struct is_complex : false_type {};
template<typename T> struct is_complex<complex<T>> : true_type {};

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct select { using type = error_tag; };

template<typename T>
struct select<T, enable_if_t<is_integral<T>::value>>{
    using type = integral_tag;
};

template<typename T>
struct select<T, enable_if_t<is_floating_point<T>::value>>{
    using type = floating_point_tag;
};

template<typename T>
struct select<T, enable_if_t<is_complex<T>::value>>{
    using type = complex_tag;
};

}
```

and each overload + the default one to select them:

```
template<typename T>
using random_tag = typename detail::select<T>::type;

template<typename T>
auto Random(floating_point_tag){
    return T{};
}

template<typename T>
auto Random(integral_tag){
    return T{};
}

template<typename T>
auto Random(complex_tag){
    return T{typename T::value_type{}, typename T::value_type{}+1};
}

template<typename T>
auto Random()
{
    return Random<T>(random_tag<T>{});
}
```

and then you can just use them:

```
int main()
{
    cout << Random<int>() << endl;
    cout << Random<float>() << endl;
    cout << Random<complex<double>>() << endl;
}
```

[live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8JNChdtDRCVoBWMp)

Answer (score 1):

Just base the new functionality on the one you already have:

```
template <>
auto Random<std::complex<double> >()
{
    return std::complex<double>{Random<double>(), Random<double>()};
}
```

As partial specialization of function templates is not allowed, you **cannot** be completely generic here and use

```
template <typename T>
auto Random<std::complex<T> >() { ... }   //error: partial specialization not allowed
```

You can get around that by either overloading or using a class - which can be partially specialized - with a static member function.

Comment: I like the idea behind this, but needing to write a different function for `float` seems a little superfluous. Same goes for integral types. However, the resulting code even with writing the overloads for OPs case is probably less than tag dispatch or class specialization approaches (and easier to read)

Answer (score 0):

With function argument deduction the underlying type can be extracted:

```
//overload for templates i.e. std::complex
template <class R, template <class...> class T> 
R underlying_t_f(T<R>);
//overload for non template types
template < class T>
 T underlying_t_f(T);

template < class T>
using underlying_t = decltype(underlying_t_f(T()));
```

Then in your code replace `T` with `underlying_t<T>`:
[Online Demo](http://rextester.com/ITGVSR76455)